# MutationObserver’s `observe` function doesn’t execute the callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mutation-observers

I’m trying to use `MutationObserver` for the first time to listen to any changes in a `<span>` element (`.mphb-price`) and update the value of a hidden field in a form which I can use later.

The value in the `<span>` element is changed by a plugin (Motopress Hotel booking). Since I don’t have any documentation / support of the plugin, my last resort is to listen to any changes of the same. However, the `observe` doesn’t somehow invoke my callback function when any changes occur.

Please provide some insight as to what I am doing wrong.

Here is my code:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.mphb-total-price .mphb-price').ready(function() {
    var target = document.querySelector('.mphb-total-price .mphb-price');

    console.log('price field is ready ' + target.textContent);

    var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
      console.log('Room rate updated');

      //record the current value of mphb-price (total cost)
      var total_cost_val = target.textContent;

      console.log('total_cost_val ' + total_cost_val);

      //update the hidden field (mphb-booking-cost)
      $('#mphb_booking_cost').attr('value', total_cost_val);
    });

    observer.observe(target, {
      childList: true,
      characterData: true,
      subtree: true
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="mphb-total-price">
  <output>Total Price: <strong class="mphb-total-price-field">
    <span class="mphb-price"><span class="mphb-currency">$</span>60</span>
  </strong></output>
</p>
```

Comment: The selector is incorrect, it should be `.mphb-total-price-field .mphb-price`, you forgot the `-field` from the first class name.

Comment: @Titus `.mphb-total-price .mphb-price` still matches `<span class="mphb-price"><span class="mphb-currency">$</span>60</span>`; `.mphb-total-price` exists.

Comment: Your code should work fine. I just put a `setTimeout(() => document.querySelector(".mphb-price").childNodes[1].textContent = 40, 1000);` within the outer `ready` function and the observer callback is being called. Are you sure that the plugin doesn’t completely _replace_ the `target` node or a node containing it?

Comment: Seems to work fine in the snippet here (when using developer tools to modify the value "60" to "603"), in Microsoft Edge Version 79.0.279.0 (Official build) dev (64-bit).

Comment: @SebastianSimon Oh, you're right, I've missed the paragraphs class name. In that case, the problem is that the element is replaced instead of changed. Observe the parent instead of the `<span>` directly.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Thanks for the edit and reply. I think you're correct mate. The span is getting replaced. I shall change the target to the outer <p> as Titus has suggested. Thanks a bunch.